# Web scraping in R by posting javascript

Tags: r, httr

On [this](http://moneycontrol.com) website, I want to enter the code "539300" at the top searchbox and get the results either (just the [new url](http://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/miscellaneous/akspintex/AKS01)) or some content (by using Xpath) from the page.

```
library(rvest); library(httr); library(RCurl)

url <- "http://www.moneycontrol.com"


res <- POST(url, body = list(search_str = "539300"), encode = "form")

pg <- read_html(content(res, as="text", encoding="UTF-8"))

html_node(pg, xpath = '//*[@id="nChrtPrc"]/div[3]/h1')
```

This results in an error

```
{xml_missing}
<NA>
```

Comment: Could you provide a snapshot of the table you are trying to scrape?

Comment: Hi, In the [new url link](http://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/miscellaneous/akspintex/AKS01) <- I want '//*[@id="nChrtPrc"]/div[3]/h1' - path which is "A K Spintex".

Comment: _"Reproduction of news articles, photos, videos or any other content in whole or in part in any form or medium without express writtern permission of moneycontrol.com is prohibited."_

Comment: Thanks @hrbrmstr ,will take care next time.

Answer (score 0):

Or just use RCurl and XML libraries.

```
library(RCurl)  
library(XML)

url <- "http://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/miscellaneous/akspintex/AKS01"
curl <- getCurlHandle()
html <- getURL(url,curl=curl, .opts = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE),followlocation=TRUE)
doc <- htmlParse(html, encoding = "UTF-8")
h1 <-xpathSApply(doc, "//*[@id='nChrtPrc']/div[3]/h1//text()")
print(h1)
```